# Is there a way to programmatically change network routes on an iOS device?

Tags: ios, iphone, routes, network-programming

Scenario:  I want to have an iOS device connect to a LAN that has no upstream Internet connection, yet still retain and use its cellular data connection.

Theoretically, it strikes me that the iOS wifi NIC and the cellular data NIC are similar enough to dual NICs in a PC that I should be able to set up routing such that any request to, say, 192.168.*.* goes through the wifi connection, and any other request goes through the cellular data connection.

I did a test to see if both NICs are active when the iOS device is connected to wifi by the following steps.

1. Ensure that my iPhone's wifi is off and that I have a good cellular data connection.
2. Disconnect my wifi router's Ethernet cable to my cable modem.
3. Connect my iPhone to the wifi router.
4. Use another iPhone that's connected only via cellular data to create a game of Words with Friends.
5. As soon as the other iPhone completed the first move, my iPhone received a notification that there was a new game to play.

This confirmed that the cellular data connection was indeed alive and well enough to receive push notifications despite the wifi NIC's being connected.

The question becomes, then, can an app programmatically connect to a given wifi network, set the cellular data network to be the default route, and route any requests to, say, 192.168.*.* to go through the wifi network?

Comment: theoretically, yes, because pretty much how the hotspot feature works. take local wifi data and NAT it out over the cell network.

Comment: @MarcB, can you point to Swift or Objective-C APIs that allow me to that?

Comment: I don't believe that there are any APIs to modify the routing table. Requests to hosts on the WiFi network will work because it is a connected network. If you want to route some requests via a router that is connected to the wifi network and still retain 3G as a default route then you may be out of luck. You may be able to use source routing in your app but i have no idea which, if any, of the socket libraries/frameworks available in iOS support this.

Comment: Also, be aware that push notifications are a special case - iOS will prefer the 3G network for notifications even when wifi is connected.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but I happen to have done some work on using multiple network interfaces on iOS.

My experiments showed that accessing via hostname results in iOS choosing the network interface it wants to use, and not trying any further interfaces if the host cannot be resolved.

If you know the DNS Server IP address for any Ethernet/WiFi based network, you can send a DNS request yourself, convert the hostname into an IP address and access via IP address.  iOS will then use the correct interface.

My guess is, that if you have the private class IP address space accessible over both connections, there's probably nothing you can do to specify which network interface should be used.