# Is there a way to programmatically change network routes on an Android 5.x device?

Tags: java, android, routes, network-programming

*Note:  similar to [Is there a way to programmatically change network routes on an iOS device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29834798/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-add-network-routes-to-an-ios-device), which I'm also asking.*

I'm seeing lots of examples out there on using the ADB shell to update routes on Android.  What I'm not seeing are programmatic ways of achieving the same.

Is there a way for an Android app to programmatically add and remove routes?

Comment: Never tried it on Android but you could include C (native) code and make standard Linux syscalls to update the networking information.  This will require `root` access, though.